# Limit range of selected days in datepicker fluttter

Tags: flutter, date, datepicker

I'm building booking application and currently I'm facing this issue where the use can select a range of days using `ShowDateRangePicker`, `showDateRangePicker`, however the use can select any range within the start and end dates but I'm asked to not let user select more than 14 days. For Example:

Startdate = 12/2/2023
endDate = 1/1/2024

and the user selected range: 12/2/2023 - 28/2/2023
In this case it should throw an error because the range exceeded the limit of 14 days. `the difference in range exceeded 14.`
Or a better one when the user reach a from date + 14 it will stop allowing them to select more days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [syncfusion_flutter_datepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) library. It has a `selectionChanged` callback that you can manipulate to limit selectable dates on the go. The snippet below shows how to limit the range to 14 days from selected `_start` day.

```js
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final DateTime _minDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _maxDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365));

  final Duration _duration = const Duration(days: 14);

  DateTime _start = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SfDateRangePicker(
        minDate: _minDate,
        maxDate: _maxDate,
        selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
        onSelectionChanged: (DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
          if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
            _start = (args.value as PickerDateRange).startDate!;
            setState(() {
              // limit the maxDate to 14 days from selected date
              _maxDate = _start.add(_duration);
            });
          }
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

For more customization refer to [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/daterangepicker/overview).

Answer (score 0):

set a DateRangePickerController inside the SfDateRangePicker and then on onSelectionChanged set the selectedDates of that controller to the list of 14 days, then the controller will not allow you to select the 15th entry.Below is the code for `DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple`, you can apply the same logic for DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range

```
List<DateTime> listOfDates = [];
late DateRangePickerController dController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  dController = DateRangePickerController();
}

..........

SfDateRangePicker(
  controller: dController,
  onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
  showNavigationArrow: true,
  toggleDaySelection: true,
  showActionButtons: true,
  enablePastDates: false,
  maxDate: DateTime(now.year + 3, 12),
  initialSelectedDates: listOfDates,
),

..........

_onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args){
  if(args.value.length <= 14){
    listOfDates = args.value;
  } else {
    setState(() {
      dController.selectedDates = listOfDates;
    });
  }
 }
```