# Flutter Date Range Picker limit to certain days

Tags: flutter, flutter-date-range-picker

How can we allow only selection of 30 days with any start date in `DateRangePicker`?

Only `firstDate` and `lastDate` can be provided, which can be restricted to 30 days starting from the provided `firstDate` only.

Comment: You may want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431028/13617136.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
final picked = await showDateRangePicker(
  context: context,
  firstDate: (DateTime.now()).subtract(Duration(days: 30)),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
  currentDate: DateTime.now(),
  saveText: 'Done',
);
```

Comment: Your suggestion gives only the last 30 days, what I actually want is to allow only 30days after selecting any previous dates.

Comment: you can show error after selection of date rage to calculate days difference under 30 days or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add below package to restrict certain dates in DateRangePicker

> calendar_date_picker2: ^0.5.2

there is "selectableDayPredicate" function available for DateRangePicker.

You can simply pass list of dates which you wants to disable in selection in range.